# how to set variable as table name in create query

Tags: mysql, jsp

im trying to create a table in mysql using jsp application. I need to set a variable in the place of tablename in the create query how to do so?

```
String name="tablename";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project", "root", "root");

String strQuery="create table "+name+"(cname varchar(25);";
Statement st=con1.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate(strQuery);
```

Comment: what is your query?

Comment: just added the code snippet. need to access my variable as the tablename in the create query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an sql syntax error in your code due to which it is failing while creating the table.

You have missed a closing parenthesis at the end of the create table query. It should be as below -

`String strQuery="create table "+name+"(cname varchar(25));";`

Your code works fine with this change, with my assumption that the database is already created.